# Is there a way to move system folders in Evolution to the top?

Tags: evolution, email-client

I like to have Sent, Junk and Trash folders just below the Inbox, like in Thunderbird. Is it possible in Evolution?

Comment: If you like Thunderbird's style why not just use that?

Comment: I like Evolution's two-line style in message list - something Thunderbird will probably never have.

Comment: If you don't like the Thunderbird style and prefer the Evolution one then why are you asking how to make Evolution more like Thunderbird?

Comment: @ParanoidPanda Are you going to suggest an EvoBird? What's wrong about customization? I don't see how your "why comments" are helpful here ;)